# Дублирование данных в item'e listview

Tags: android

Есть ArrayList<Option>, Option - объект, который имеет параметры "имя_опции" и ArrayList<Function>. Каждая function - это по сути строка для checkbox'a. Весь первоночальный список опций хочу отобразить в listview, где каждый item - это linearlayout, включающий textview, checkbox'ы-функции добавляются  программно. Код

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Option option = options.get(position);
    if(v == null || !(v instanceof LinearLayout)){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }
    TextView optionNameTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.optionNameTextView);
    if (option != null && option.option_name != null){
        optionNameTextView.setText(option.option_name);
        if (option.functions != null){
            ((LinearLayout)v).addView(addFunction(options.get(position).functions.get(0)));
            ArrayList<Function> functions = option.functions;
            for (int i = 0; i < functions.size(); i++){
                ((LinearLayout)v).addView(addFunction(functions.get(i)));
            }
        }

    }
    return v;
}

private CheckBox addFunction(Function function) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
    checkBox.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black_text_color));
    checkBox.setClickable(false);
    if (function != null && function.name != null){
        checkBox.setText(function.name);
        if (function.value != null && function.value.equals("1")){
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    return checkBox;
}
```

ЛистВью заполняю в DialogFragment. Код

```
     public static OptionsDialogFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Option> options){
    OptionsDialogFragment optionsDialogFragment = new OptionsDialogFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("options", (Serializable) options);
    optionsDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return optionsDialogFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_options, null);
    ArrayList<Option> options = (ArrayList<Option>) getArguments().getSerializable("options");
    optionsListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.optionsListView);
    optionsListView.setDivider(null);
    optionArrayAdapter = new OptionArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_option, options);
    optionsListView.setAdapter(optionArrayAdapter);
    return v;
}
```

В AsynTask'e, в методе onPostExecute заполняю фрагмент

```
   if (result.options != null){
                optionsDialogFragment = OptionsDialogFragment.newInstance(result.options);
            }
```

Вобщем проблема в том, что количество опций нормальное, а чекбоксы в каждый item добавляются из других опций. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: вообще, если добавлять программно в item что угодно, почему-то дублируется добавление в каждый item. т.е. у меня например 15 объектов опций. программно я решила добавить текствью с наименованием опций, в результате получилось 15 айтимов, каждый состоит из 15 текствью. будто где-то ещё один цикл есть(

Comment: первая часть кода - это кусок из getview класса OptionArrayAdapter

Comment: а проверяли, точно ли в option.functions содержатся нуные функции? может они не правильно добавляются еще до этого?

Comment: проверяла, всё нормально)

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что проблема в коде, который идет перед тем, что вы выложили. Покажите-ка весь код функции getView.

Comment: Добавила код. Может проблемы в невнимательности. Но не могу найти ошибку. Данные (result.options) приходят и я отправляю верные - проверяла. На этом шаге всё хорошо.

Comment: Уберите проверку if(v == null || !(v instanceof LinearLayout)){ и в кадом запросе view пересоздавайте его. Если ошибка исчезнет, то дело в динамическом добавлении view в ваш лэйаут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что у вас в convertView приходит ранее созданный View в котором содержатся ранее добавленные элементы. Вы делаете проверку на null, и естественно он не равен, так как был создан ранее вами. 
Мой вам совет: добавьте в xml(***v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);***) дополнительный контейнер, который будет содержать конкретно динамически добавляемые элементы. Этот контейнер каждый раз очищайте, перед циклом

```
for (int i = 0; i < functions.size(); i++){
                ((LinearLayout)v).addView(addFunction(functions.get(i)));
            }
```

Иначе у вас будет плохо.

**Советы по оптимизации:**
не надо проверять  !(v instanceof LinearLayout) - это ненужная и лишняя операция, к тому же весьма дорогая, достаточно оставить проверку равенство null.

Так же советую инициализировать однажды в конструкторе адаптера

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Потому что это тоже может сказаться на производительности.